# Android emulator restart / can't access via USB after frida-server start

Tags: android, android-emulator, frida

I used Frida with Android 7.1.1 emulator that is part of Android studio more or less successfully.
Now I tried to do the same with higher version of Android - 8.0 or 8.1. It behaves differently and I got some problems that I don't fully understand.

I run frida server with `adb shell "/path-to-dir/frida-server &"`. Nothing visually happens when I use this command on Android 7.1.1 - and then everything works fine.
But I see that emulator restarts when I use this command on Android 8.0 or 8.1 (it is visible and I have messages like `INFO    | Boot completed in XXX ms` in log) . I'm not sure is it good or bad because after such a restart I see that frida server is running inside emulator:

```
generic_x86:/ # ps -ef | grep frida                                                                                                                         
root          3800     1 73 13:39:42 ?    00:00:08 frida-server
root          5457  3790 0 13:39:53 pts/0 00:00:00 grep frida
generic_x86:/ #
```

So, probably frida server is up and running as it should.
But there is another problem - I can't do anything with it because it appears that USB connection with emulator is somehow disrupted after the restart. Everything works via ADB but frida itself doesn't see USB device anymore:

```
[user@pc]$ frida-ps -U -a
Failed to enumerate applications: timeout was reached                   
[user@pc]$
```

(other frida commands behave similar way - they don't see USB device and end up with a timeout).
The same command works fine just before I start frida server.

I can repair it if I go to Settings->Developer options inside the emulator and switch USB debugging off and then on again. Command `frida-ps -U -a` works successfully immediately after this action. But this action kills frida server.

I'm trying to understand what I do wrong and how to keep frida working with emulator via USB after frida server start. Or, if it isn't possible - how to configure IP access to the emulator. I can ping host from the emulator but can't reach emulator from the host (I suspect it is because of NAT but not sure how to get access in a good way).

Update about rooting the emulator.
I'm starting frida server this way:

```
[user@pc]$ adb root
restarting adbd as root
[user@pc]$ adb remount
remount succeeded
[user@pc]$ adb shell "/data/local/tmp/frida-server &"
 < here it stops and waits without exit >
```

so I'm not sure that I need to root the emulator (and I haven't done it with Android 7.1.1)

Comment: Hm.. I had this thought but... 1) I can do "su" inside emulator - you may see "#" is present in my "ps -ef" output; 2) I haven't rooted Android 7.1.1 image. Taking these 2 items into account - are you sure that I should root Android 8.1 emulator? And I did "adb root" before starting frida server from "adb shell" command

Comment: I am a bit surprised that `adb root` works. I you start frida-server afterwards via adb it should have root privileges. Most of the time I work with real devices because most apps don't work "correctly" on emulators (or better don't want to run there). BTW: It is quite normal that even if you start frida-server in background the adb shell command does not return. Not sure why but the behavior is just normal.

Comment: @Robert, I fully agree with your comments if it would be a real device. But my experience shows me that I have root access to emulator and something else goes wrong... I just can't catch what it is exactly. I suspect that I need to switch to IP access to the emulator but not sure...

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I tried to do the same with Android 9.0 and succeeded.
[Frida website](https://frida.re/docs/android/) says *"Also note that most of our recent testing has been taking place on a Pixel 3 running Android 9"* and *"Another option is using an emulator, ideally with a Google-provided Android 9 emulator image for arm or arm64. (x86 may work too but has gone through significantly less testing.)"*
It appears Android 8.x x86 emulator doesn't have good compatibility with Frida and have some issues as I haven't done anything different with 7.1.1 or 9.0.